# how to JOIN table with WHERE clause and also show non existent rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The title may sound a bit confusing, but let me explain:
I have three tables:
**store**

```
storeID | name
1       | store1
2       | store2
3       | store3
```

**product**

```
productID | name
1         | ball
2         | cup
```

**store_product**

```
storeID_fk | productID_fk
2          | 1
1          | 2
3          | 2
```

What I want to archive is a result like the following:

```
storeID | name  | storeID_fk | productID_fk
1       | store1| NULL       | NULL
2       | store2| 2          | 1
3       | store3| NULL       | NULL
```

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM `store` 
LEFT JOIN `store_product` on storeID = storeID_fk  
WHERE productID_fk = 1;
```

But this only returns:

```
storeID | name  | storeID_fk | productID_fk
2       | store2| 2          | 1
```

How can I also display the empty/not existing rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a `left join`, put the right side table's conditions in the `ON` clause to get true left join behavior. (When in `WHERE`, you get regular `inner join` result.)

```
SELECT * FROM `store` 
LEFT JOIN `store_product` on storeID = storeID_fk  
    AND productID_fk = 1
```